# Scalar question regarding homogeneous coordinates

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

Let $x$, $y$, $z$ be three collinear points in homogeneous coordinates. Show there are scalars $j$, $k$, and $l$ such that $jx + ky = lz$, with $j$, $k$, and $l$ not all $0$.

I started with the definition of collinear points. That is, $jx_i + ky_i + lz_i = 0$, with $j$, $k$, and $l$ not all $0$.

Then I continued by saying that $jx_i + ky_i = -lz_i$.

I'm stuck and would appreciate some help. Thanks. I hate geometry.

Comment: You also need the condition that the scalars are not all zero.

Comment: Yes, I wrote that.

Comment: That condition isn’t in the assertion that you’re trying to prove, though. Having the points be distinct is also important, though you can probably assume that.